# GAE migration from java 7 to 8 on android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-app-engine

I'm trying to migrate Google App Engine to java8 using the migration guide below.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8

it says that: -

> To have App Engine run your application in the Java 8 runtime, add
>   `<runtime>java8</runtime>`
>   to your appengine-web.xml file and redeploy the app.

when i try to do that i get the following error at the "runtime" tag:

> element runtime is not allowed here

did i miss anything? This GAE is a backend module for my android app.  I am using gradle on Android studio as the development environment.

prior to this, I  have also migrated successfully to cloudEndpoints V2 using https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating

[image]

edit: added error log

```
Jan 03, 2018 3:39:52 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing D:\GitlabProjects\XushuNarrator\backend\build\exploded-backend\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Unrecognized element <runtime>
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processSecondLevelNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:183)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:65)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:132)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:76)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:165)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
```

edit 2: the following is the gradle build for the backend. (After migration from V1 to V2)

```
//MIGRATION GUIDE
//https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // V2: Add the new App Engine and Endpoints Frameworks plugin dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.2'

//         classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.59'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
// V2: Apply new App Engine and Endpoints Framework server plugins
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'
//apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
//    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.59'
//    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.59'
//    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.59'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.9'

    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    // V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
    compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.7'

}

// V2: Define deployment configuration using the new App Engine plugin
// with the appengine closure
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration

    deploy {   // deploy configuration

        // The following is used for acceptance tests and
        // is not required for a migration. 
        project = "ultra-tube-89909"
        version = "2" //changed to GAE API v2

        /*
        Run the following command to initalize the Cloud SDK:
             gcloud init
        Use Application Default Credentials:
             gcloud auth application-default login
        Install the app-engine-java component:
             gcloud components install app-engine-java
         */
//        project = findProperty("appengine.deploy.project")
//        version = findProperty("appengine.deploy.version")

        def promoteProp = findProperty("appengine.deploy.promote")
        if (promoteProp != null) {
            promote = new Boolean(promoteProp)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your Gradle Build file?

Comment: I have just tested with a sample application adding the `<runtime>java8</runtime>` tag and it works for me. Are you working with App Engine Standard or Flexible? The error comes up on deployment or when local-testing the app with the Development Server?

Answer (score 2):

It's highly advised to keep the Google Cloud SDK up to date as there are bug [fixes and new features](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes) introduced quite often. So, I recommend that you to update your Cloud SDK version by the running the following command:

```
gcloud components update
```

Also, according to the [migration documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating-android#update_the_backendbuildgradle) the following change is needed to upgrade the Gradle App Engine plugin, so that it may recognize the new ‘Java8’ runtime:

```
classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same thing but even though I had the error

> element runtime is not allowed here

I still redeployed the backend via Gradle and it all worked. Then when I check my google cloud console, the newly deployed app engine version has java 8 listed as the run time and my app still works. So all seems ok.

Comment: I had the same thing too. It's disconcerting to still have "element runtime is not allowed here" indicated in red as an error on Android Studio, but otherwise everything seems ok. Presumably just an Android Studio bug?